# Show all errors that will occur in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a huge bulk insert that causes errors:

```
DECLARE @row_terminator CHAR;
SET @row_terminator = CHAR(10); -- or char(10)

DECLARE @stmt NVARCHAR(2000);

SET @stmt = '
  BULK INSERT accn_billed_procedures
   FROM ''F:\2011-Dec\accn_billed_procedures_201112062112.txt.gz''
   WITH 
      (
        firstrow=2,
FIELDTERMINATOR = ''|''  ,
ROWS_PER_BATCH=10000
   ,ROWTERMINATOR='''+@row_terminator+'''
   )'
exec sp_executesql @stmt;
SET @stmt = '
  BULK INSERT accn_billed_procedures
   FROM ''F:\2011-Dec\accn_billed_procedures_201112072112.txt.gz''
   WITH 
      (
        firstrow=2,
FIELDTERMINATOR = ''|''  ,
ROWS_PER_BATCH=10000
   ,ROWTERMINATOR='''+@row_terminator+'''
   )'
exec sp_executesql @stmt;
SET @stmt = '
  BULK INSERT accn_billed_procedures
   FROM ''F:\2011-Dec\accn_billed_procedures_201112082112.txt.gz''
   WITH 
      (
        firstrow=2,
FIELDTERMINATOR = ''|''  ,
ROWS_PER_BATCH=10000
   ,ROWTERMINATOR='''+@row_terminator+'''
   )'
exec sp_executesql @stmt;
SET @stmt = '
  BULK INSERT accn_billed_procedures
   FROM ''F:\2011-Dec\accn_billed_procedures_201112092112.txt.gz''
   WITH 
      (
        firstrow=2,
FIELDTERMINATOR = ''|''  ,
ROWS_PER_BATCH=10000
   ,ROWTERMINATOR='''+@row_terminator+'''
   )'
exec sp_executesql @stmt;
SET @stmt = '
  BULK INSERT accn_billed_procedures
   FROM ''F:\2011-Dec\accn_billed_procedures_201112102112.txt.gz''
   WITH 
      (
        firstrow=2,
FIELDTERMINATOR = ''|''  ,
ROWS_PER_BATCH=10000
   ,ROWTERMINATOR='''+@row_terminator+'''
   )'
exec sp_executesql @stmt;
```

I would like to know all the errors (or at least a lot of the errors) that are cause.

it doesnt matter to me if it will require me to run everything in order to get the list of errors.

**I just want to whether it is possible to show all errors that a sql statement will generate in sql server 2008?**

Comment: Show the errors before they even happen? Sounds like sci-fi :-)

Comment: @marc_s what we are doing today was sci-fi 10 years ago

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx

```
BEGIN TRY
    -- Table does not exist; object name resolution
    -- error not caught.
    SELECT * FROM NonexistentTable;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT 
        ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber
        ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
END CATCH
```

Answer (score 1):

`BULK INSERT` has an ERRORFILE parameter. ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx )